# Renaming WeatherForecastController produces 404 error

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

I am using the latest Angular template plus ASP.Net Core WebApi projects in VS 2022. I am trying to convert for my use by renaming the `WeatherForecastController`. I find that `WeatherForecastPlop2Controller` works fine, but `BobWeatherForecastController` does not work.
I have been playing for last whole two days trying to get multiple controllers working with the sample projects. I can see them working via Swagger with API port, but for some reason only the `WeatherForecastController` calls work via the proxy.
I am new to web development so any pointers would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I had a problem changing setupProxy settings in a React app and found that I simply had to close the console windows to get them to refresh.  Also, the names are case sensitive in the frontend code.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to replace `[Route("[controller]")]` to `[Route("WeatherForecast")]` in `BobWeatherForecastController`.

```
[ApiController]
    [Route("WeatherForecast")]

    public class BobWeatherForecastController: ControllerBase
    {
    }
```

So that the routing of `BobWeatherForecastController` is still `WeatherForecast/...`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I now see that you method would also work.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that the problem was with the proxy.conf.js file;

```
const PROXY_CONFIG = [
  {
   context: ["/weatherforecast", ],
   target: "https://localhost:7085",
   secure: false
  }
]

module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```

The proxy middleware seems to not care what comes after the context. Which is why `WeatherForecastPlop2Controller` works but `BobWeatherForecastController` does not. So to get the renamed Controller to work in my Angular app I needed to match the new name in this proxy file.

Comment: Were you able to completely rename the controller?